# Identifying custom lines in .Dgn file using DgnLib

Tags: dgn

I cannot identify custom lines in .Dgn file.

In Microstation 7, we can assign the style value of lines from 0 to 7 but if  lines are customed lines, they always have the style value is 0.

How can we identify them?

[image: Identify customed lines]

Comment: Please elaborate on the arcobjects aspect of this question.

Comment: Hi, after getting detail from dgn, I use arcobjects to draw elements in the pagelayoutcontrol